# Crop image in non-rectangular shape in Android like Face fighter

Tags: android, image, crop

I want to crop image in some shape in Android.

By using `Camera Intent`, i can only do this :

[image: Camera Intent]

I don't know how to do this :

[image: face fighter]

Is it possible?

Comment: There isn't any android app for doing it, but you can implement it yourself if you really need this.

Comment: Cam scanner for document scanning has such a capability.

Comment: share some code or hint if you found solution !